# Find the area of given triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In a triangle $ABC$, where $a=8$, $c=1$ and $\cos (A-C) ={16\over 65}$.

Where $(a,b,c)$ are sides and $(A,B,C)$ are angles.

How can we find the area of the triangle $ABC$?

A hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Problem is taken from which exercise book? Does it represent a triangle that can be constructed?

Comment: my teacher makes all questions himself :)

Comment: So what could be his answer for the above question?

Comment: It is 8 i think, ill check and let u know.

Comment: Its a right angled triangle

Comment: OK, can we see construction of the triangle ?

Comment: i just did normal math. I applied tha tangent rule and calculated tanB/2 . Came out to be 45°

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** The [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) says
$$
\sin(A)=8\sin(C)\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{16}{65}
&=\cos(A)\cos(C)+\sin(A)\sin(C)\tag{2}\\
\left(\frac{16}{65}-8\sin^2(C)\right)^2
&=\left(1-64\sin^2(C)\right)\left(1-\sin^2(C)\right)\tag{3}\\
\frac{256}{4225}-\frac{256}{65}\sin^2(C)+64\sin^4(C)
&=1-65\sin^2(C)+64\sin^4(C)\tag{4}\\
\sin^2(C)
&=\frac1{65}\tag{5}\\
\end{align}
$$
This means that
$$
\sin^2(A)=\frac{64}{65}\quad\cos^2(A)=\frac1{65}\quad\sin^2(C)=\frac1{65}\quad\cos^2(C)=\frac{64}{65}\tag{6}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(A+C)
&=\cos(A)\cos(C)-\sin(A)\sin(C)\\
&=\frac8{65}-\frac8{65}\\[2pt]
&=0\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
What does this say about $B$, the angle between $a$ and $c$?

---

**Note:** Since $A,C\le\pi$, we have $\sin(A),\sin(C)\ge0$. However, only given $(6)$, $\cos(A),\cos(C)$ may not both be positive. Therefore, we know that $\sin(A)\sin(C)=\frac8{65}$, but we only know that $|\cos(A)\cos(C)|=\frac8{65}$. However, $(2)$ tells us that $\cos(A)\cos(C)=\frac8{65}$.

Comment: we can do this by tangent formula also. Its easier that way.

Comment: Thanks for your effort though. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Given

$$ c,a,\quad \delta = C-A  $$

[image]

$$ C-A = \gamma- \alpha = \delta $$

Construct double angle $ 2 \alpha $ at vertex A.

Law of Sines on $ \Delta ABC $

$$ \frac{c}{a}= \frac{\sin (\delta+\alpha)}{\sin \alpha} \tag1$$

Trig expand and algebraically simplify

$$ \tan \alpha= \frac {\sin \delta}{( c/a -\cos  \delta )} \rightarrow \alpha_{1,2} \tag2 $$

$$ \alpha_2 =\alpha_1 + \pi \tag3$$

$$ \beta = (\pi- \delta- 2 \alpha _{1,2}) \tag4 $$

$$ \gamma = (\pi-  \alpha _{1,2} -\beta) \tag5 $$

One value suffices.

Area

$$ \frac12 \,a \,c \sin \beta = .. $$

Also checked all the results numerically

EDIT1:

If we use supplementary angle for angles assuming it as an ambiguous case, all conditions given could be correctly realized, but this should be seen in a construction.

Comment: Check me, but from $\frac ca=\frac{\sin(\delta+\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}$, I get $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(\delta)}{c/a-\cos(\delta)}$

Comment: $a$ and $c$ are given. Where did we get $b$?

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, typo  corrected.Else all tally.

Comment: The way the question is stated, $a\gt c$, so $\delta=C-A\lt0$. This makes some of the diagrams, and the results when plugging into the formulas, a bit confusing. Geometry with negative quantities, though often algebraically fine, seems quite unsettling.

Comment: Yes, indeed. When I too felt that way..just reached for coffee :) but seeing your comment after  calculation regarding.Trig..it feels perhaps something was not recognized here,..it is the *ambiguous case*( given angle not included between given sides)?. In any case, a geometric construction of the triangle would  settle everything,. shall get back.